# Tabs and columns in LaTeX

Tags: tables, tabbing

I'm looking for a way to do something like this in LaTeX:

```
2006-now       good years
               had a lot of fun

2002-2005      not good years
               I just wish I knew how to do this
```

How do I achieve this?

EDIT: My cobbled attempt is this:

```
2006-now \ \ \ \ \ \= good years
          \> had a lot of fun

2002-2005 \> not good years
          \> I just wish I knew how to do this
```

But this doesn't seem very professional.

Comment: If this is for a CV, you should consider a specialized style file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`tabular` environment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Basic_examples) which is fine for trivial tables. The linked article covers more complex ones, too.